# What are the costs of the various different engines in current use?

Tags: launch, engines, ssme, rd-180, merlin-1d

This may be impossible to answer, since the data is often not disclosed.

But in an article, [about ULA getting RD-180's from Russia](http://thehill.com/policy/defense/204316-contractor-speeds-up-deliveries-of-russian-engines#ixzz2zthK4wBf) it claims:

> Each engine reportedly costs between \$11 to \$15 million.

I have never seen prices quoted for a Merlin 1C or 1D, or say an RS-68 (Or RS-68A), an SSME or an NK-33/AJ-26. Comparing different engines in terms of cost could be very interesting.

Of course, an RD-180 has the thrust of 10 Merlins or so, or almost 2 RS-68s or SSME's so probably worth noting common number of units of each used in a typical launcher.

Comment: This seems awfully broad as it currently stands, perhaps a more narrow focus would help?

Comment: Many different dimensions complicate things: reusability, power range, fuel type, throttle range, restartability, etc. Comparing on cost alone (while not in and of itself easy) will be somewhat meaningless.

Comment: @AaronN.Tubbs Agreed, but it is a starting point.  One RD-180 suffices where 9 Merlin 1Ds are needed. BUt knowing the price of both provides insight into design choices made.

Answer (score 1):

We can put an upper bound on the cost of a Merlin; SpaceX quotes a cost of [\$135M for a Falcon Heavy](http://www.spacex.com/about/capabilities) launch. That includes 28 Merlins. If you assume the engines are half the total cost of the rocket, that's 2.4M per engine. Of course it could be considerably less...

Comment: Not a terrible metric. Not a great metric, but a first approximation, I will take it.

Comment: A Falcon Heavy launch costs 85M and Falcon 9 61M. If you approximate the Heavy as a Falcon 9 complete system plus 2 extra first stages, the cost for the first stage hardware is roughly 12M, so the engines are under 1.3M each.